# Magento2 poor LCP on product page

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to improve the LCP (core vitals) of my product page.
I'm using latest 2.4.1 Magento version.

Although LCP are quite good on homepage and category page (1.7s & 1.4s), it is very bad on product page (3,1s to 3,7 s), and we aim at a CLP of 1.2, or near this figure.

The very best result I get is 3,1s.
All images, JS, CSS are already optimised, using WebP, defering JS, using critical css.

Even on a clean M2 with demo data, the LCP is bad.

As anyone succeed in improving this CLP ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Magento 2 has very low score in a lot of frontend metrics (backend is slow too, but mostly of times you can deal with it using FPC and other tools).

For frontend optmization you can try:

- Use a PWA for frontend (like Vue Storefront https://www.vuestorefront.io/)
- Try something experimental like Hyvä Theme https://hyva.io/
- Follow some best practices and guidelines for optimization:

  - https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6758810946250043392/
  - https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6758232448640856065/

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply.

For PWA, I think it is a bit too early to adopt it on a ecommerce plateform, and the cost should be quite high... if you need some customisation.

Hyva Theme: they have great results ! For sure, but will probably lack of some features but it's the first time I saw great result for a M2 page... so well done to them !

Best practices, think I followed most of them already...

Maybe a thing to look at : https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-tools ?

Comment: @Jack , some of the optimizations listed in the LinkedIn articles I sent aren't too obvious, so it worths trying:
- Override modules and remove unused css and js
- Implement Advance Js bundling, Here is link (https://lnkd.in/ebcvVMM)
- Use Terser for Js minification
This guy achieved a score of 99 in Lighthouse without use of PWA... I will try some of his advices soon.I never tried the tool from Yireo you sent, so I can't say it will optimize frontend, but I'm sure disabling modules will make your deploy and backend faster. I think a benchmark after aplying their module should be nice too.

Comment: yes in fact, I'm at 99 in Gtmetrix Performance score too (so core metrics), but only on desktop - and Google tests the page using 3G with a mobile device...

Testing my product page with 3G and Iphone device gives deceptive E grade with a note of 42 :(

As the page is already highly optimised, I don't really see/know what I can do more.
Disabling some modules, yes I can do that, but will it optimise the frontend too ?

Comment: If possible, send your project URL. I am curious to identify what remains to be optimized. It looks like you followed all the recommendations. About disabling modules, I was talking about the Github link you sent. Yireo module seens to disable standard Magento modules, but I also have doubts that this will help to improve frontend performance.